# Normal approximation to binomial

Tags: probability, statistics

60,550,241 voted for Trump

60,981,118 voted for Hillary

What is the probability this would happen if there was equal probability for voting for each candidate?

I know we have to find the standard deviation and then set up some sort of ratio, but I am not exactly sure. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: It depends on how you interpret "the probability **this** would happen." Does **this** mean this exact outcome (exactly 60,550,241 votes for Trump and exactly 60,981,118 for Hillary), or does it mean an outcome at least this favorable for Trump, or does it mean any outcome where Trump wins, or something else?

Comment: I believe this meant that what were the odds that Trump and Hillary got their respective vote counts. In a world where each candidate would have otherwise gotten a 50/50 votes. I think I'm supposed to use the standard deviation to find the likelihood of a result like this occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large $n,$ $\text{binomial}(n, p) \approx N(np, np(1-p)).$ So if we assume that the vote can be described as $\text{binomial}({\sim}121\text{ million}, 0.5),$ the standard deviation based on the normal approximation would be $\sqrt{np(1-p))} \approx 5500, $ and the chance of the margin being over 400,000 ($\sim 80$ standard deviations) would be very, very small.